# How to trim string using predefined special characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

this is my string:

```
lid://abcde.ln.ln_dev_510
```

how to get the number after '_' using LTRIM, RTRIM.

Thank You.

Comment: What have *YOU* tried so far? Please show us some effort of your own!

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

`LTRIM` and `RTRIM` are for removing trailing and leading **spaces** in string. You can simply get the number using the following query:

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(MAX)='lid://abcde.ln.ln_dev_510'
SET @t = REVERSE(@t)

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@t,1,CHARINDEX('_',@t)-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

In you case using [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188006.aspx) you can get the values after the last `_`.

```
DECLARE @StringValue AS VARCHAR (500) = 'lid://abcde.ln.ln_dev_510';
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(PARSENAME(@StringValue, 1), '_', '.'), 1)
```

Output will be:

```
510
```

Answer (score 2):

At first we REVERSE the string backward to find last occurrence of '_' symbol (since SQL Server got no other way to search for last occurrence of string in another, we need to reverse the string). The number we get minus 1 is exactly number of symbols we must to take from RIGHT part of original string.

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = 'lid://abcde.ln.ln_dev_510'

SELECT RIGHT(@str,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@str))-1)
```

Output:

```
510
```

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to explain the functions you used since OP does not seem to be familiar with their usage.

Comment: Explanation added! Thanks for noticing! :)